# Fail to upgrade operator in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I'm writing an operator by `operator-sdk` and I have created statefulset pod in operator by using k8s api like :
`r.client.Create(context.TODO(), statefulset)`

It's works correctly and the `statefulset pod` is crated. But now I want to upgrade the operator already run in k8s so that I can add some command for pod like

```
Containers: []corev1.Container{{
    Command: []string{.....}
```

First I build the newer operator image and delete the operator in k8s. The k8s quickly restarts the the operator by using the newer image(`kubectl describe pod  myoperator` show newer images is used).

Second I delete the `statefulset pod` and the k8s also restarts the `statefulset pod` in seconds.

But I find the `statefulset pod` doesn't contain the command I added in the operator(`kubectl describe pod  statefulsetpod`). If I delete all the resources in k8s and redeploy them, It works.

I have a lot of resources need be created by the operator so I don't want deploy all the resources.

Comment: can you provide statefulset specification and be more concrete what exactly wanna change in pod?

Comment: thanks @Vitalii , the spec of the statefulset is pretty simple, I only change the string in the `Command ` item of the statefulset pod but not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) itself instead of `statefulset pod`. The problem is when you delete `statefulset pod` - new pod automatically creates from old `statefulset` spec.

Once you delete/recreate `statefulset` - as expected you schedule proper updated pods.

Probably you can add additional logic to `operator` that will patch already existed `statefulset` - that can be resolution for avoiding redeploy statefulset each time.